# Determine if an ellipse is inside a disk if all four vertices are in the disk.

Tags: geometry

given a circle of radius R and an ellipse.  If all four vertices of the ellipse are contained within the circle, then is the entire ellipse contained within the circle.

Note: points of the ellipse can be on the circle (namely the vertices)

Comment: What do you mean by the vertices of an ellipse?

Comment: I assume the endpoints of the major and minor axes.

Comment: Do the circle and ellipse have to share the same center? If not, this is not always true.([picture](https://imgur.com/a/Fmjx4VA), [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4bhyp5uvko)).

Comment: If you want to find out if they do intersect given the vertices, the answer is pretty hard but I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3678498/498717) answer and [this](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionOfEllipses.pdf) document (section 4.2 on). You can get more info and more Stack Exchange posts by searching "ellipse intersection test."

Comment: thanks everyone.  After I thought about it, there are lots of ways to show this is false.  I looked at radius of curvature at the minor axis vertex. That link is very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having all four vertices in the circle does not mean that the whole ellipse will be in the circle. One specific counterexample would be $$\frac{3}{2}x^{2}+4\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}=1$$
whose vertices lie inside the unit circle but parts of the ellipse lie outside, as seen in [this desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jbzyqqko9g).

Edit: Even a circle can work: $$4\left(x-\frac{2}{5}\right)^2+4\left(y-\frac{2}{5}\right)^{2}=1$$

Comment: one of the vertices in your example is on the circle, which OP has prohibited

Comment: He stated "Note: points of the ellipse can be on the circle (namely the vertices)"

Comment: And $-1/2$ can be replaced by $-1/2+.01$ if you want to make the vertex not touch.